# How large are the zones?

Tags: zombicide

I've tried a few missions now but I'm a bit confused still with how large a zone really is. Is there any indication somewhere where one zone ends and the next one starts? (outside of buildings)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the streets a zone is a variable-sized area edged by building walls and pedestrian crossings.

From the [Zombicide rulebook](https://zombicide.com/dl/rulebook-zombicide-season-1.pdf) (page 5):

> **ZONE**
>
> Inside a building, a Zone is a room.
>
> On the street, a Zone is the area between two pedestrian
> crossings and the walls of buildings along
> the street. A single Zone may extend over two tiles
> or even four tiles.

For example, in the following image, the red boxes identify the different zones of the map:

[image: Zombicide map with zones identified]